# Unable to save a stored procedure which contains a temporary table creation and update query

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, temporary-tables

I am unable to save my procedure in Postgres. The procedure contains a temporary table creation and update query.

Here is my query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE account_report_v2()
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
    BEGIN;
    
        CREATE TEMP TABLE report_data on commit drop AS (select * from tests);

        update report_data set 
            df_name = dfn,
            dl_name = dln
        From
        (
            select  id  ,first_name dfn,last_name dln from df_info
        )AS subquery
        where (report_data.provider_id :: varchar(50)) = (subquery.id :: varchar(50));
        
    COMMIT;
$$;

CALL account_report_v2();
```

When I try to save the procedure, postgres gives the following error:

> **relation "report_data" does not exist.**

Here is how it looks like in pgAdmin 4:

[image]

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify `LANGUAGE plpgsql` rather than `LANGUAGE sql`.

The function does not consist of only SQL statements, and other than for PL/pgSQL, the SQL language validator parses the SQL statements and checks them for validity.